# How to use Angular JS filter with ICanHaz.js template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, icanhaz.js

I'm trying to apply an [Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) filter from within an [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/) template... but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ICanHaz.js"></script>

<!-- icanhaz template -->
<script id="a_template" class="partial" type="text/html">
  <div class="whocares">
      {{ variable | angular_filter }}
  </div>
</script>
```

It doesn't throw any errors, but the `variable` just doesn't show up. I'm guessing that the problem is that the angular filter doesn't see the variable (or visa versa).

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why would you complicate things so much, but the quick fix here would be to define a scope variable  and use it in a regular angular way:

```
$scope.variable = "whatever icanhaz outputs";
```

That way, the filter would be applied to angular controller's scope variable instead of trying to hack in the ICanHaz variable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in this situation because I'm gradually refactoring an existing project (with Angular) that already has a ton of icanhaz templates in place. Can you add a little more detail to your answer to show how the filter works?

Comment: I thought you're doing something like that. Sounds like the less mid-steps you have, the better. My example is purely angular - by using the angular template to output the content of the scope variable. The "trick" is to assign the icanhaz variable contents to it.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the help. I'm leaning towards biting the bullet and refactoring the templates into angular, but you've answered the original question as best possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with less mid-steps: you'd just waste time on temporal solutions. You're welcome and good luck with it!